# In MySQL 8.0, I have a column with a data field type of GEOMETRY. Why is the value from my query not being shown consistently?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, spatial-query, mysql-8.0

I have a field `random_point` where the data-type is `GEOMETRY`. Viewing this value as a GeoJSON, I get the following: `{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -61.0, 13.0 ] }`. When I query however, why is it that I'm getting inconsistent results?

Query: `SELECT ST_Latitude(random_point) FROM table ...`

Result: `-61.00000000000001`

Expected Result: `-61.0`

Edit: The SRID type I am using is 4326. I speculate this may something to do with the results...

Comment: Are you sure it's not `-60.99999`? That's about the same as `-61.0`, it's just a different amount of rounding.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8a38496f84021f0db28945934bb9b97).

Comment: @wchiquito You have reproduced my problem correctly. I just malformed my result in the actual question. Why is the value not -61.0 though instead of -61.00000000000001